# HTTP запрос к Web Api uTorrent Golang

Tags: http, golang

У меня есть локальный сервер uTorrent на убунте, к которому я хочу написать обертку на Go. Авторизироваться у меня получается корректно, я правильно(насколько я могу судить) получаю из html токен. Проблемы начинаются, когда я пытаюсь получить список всех файлов, мне возвращается 400 и invalid request. Самое интересное, что при абсолютно тех же действиях на другом языке у меня все работает нормально, что вносит еще больше путаницы.

```
func (torrentServer *TorrentServer) Auth() error {

    torrentServer.client = &http.Client{}
    request, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "http://192.168.1.127:8080/gui/token.html", nil)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    request.Header.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + torrentServer.basicAuth("login", "password"))
    resp, err := torrentServer.client.Do(request)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    token, err := torrentServer.parseToken(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    torrentServer.token = token
    resp.Body.Close()
    return nil
}

func (torrentServer *TorrentServer) GetListOfTorrents() error{
    fmt.Println(torrentServer.token)

    request, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "http://192.168.1.127:8080/gui/?list=1&token="+torrentServer.token, nil)
    if err != nil {
       return err
    }
    request.Header.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + torrentServer.basicAuth("login", "password"))
    resp, err := torrentServer.client.Do(request)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    fmt.Println(resp)
    data, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    fmt.Println(string(data))
    var f interface{}
    err = json.Unmarshal(data, &f)
    if err != nil{
        return err
    }
    fmt.Println(f.(map[string]interface{}))
    return nil

}
```

Comment: таки ты нашел ответ на вопрос свой, в чем была причина? :)